# Searching an array and getting results

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, So I am wanting to find information in an array and get a block returned based on the credentials passed. The way I am doing it right now is not working, I'm looking for a shorter process and a more fool proof process.

Right now I have this:

```
public function get_product($product_id, $color, $size)
{
    $results = $this->pf->get('products/'.$product_id);

    $vars = $results['variants'];

    $details = array();

    foreach($vars as $var)
    {
        if(!in_array($product_id, $details))
        {
            if($var['product_id'] == $product_id)
            {
                if($var['size'] == $size)
                {
                    if($var['color'] == $color)
                    {
                        $details[$var['id']] = array(
                            'id' => $var['id'],
                            'name' => $var['name'],
                            'image' => $var['image'],
                            'price' => $var['price'],
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $details;
}
```

This receives a product_id, a color, and a size. Sometimes `$color` is null, Sometimes `$size` is null, and sometimes both `$color` and `$size` are null and we just need to find the one array that matches the `$product_id`.

What I am wanting returned is this:

```
$details[$var['id']] = array(
     'id' => $var['id'],
     'name' => $var['name'],
     'image' => $var['image'],
     'price' => $var['price'],
);
```

Right now nothing gets returned. `$results` returns this for an example: (This is what I need to search.)

```
{
"code": 200,
"result": {
    "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "POSTER",
        "brand": null,
        "model": "Poster",
        "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/poster_18x24.jpg",
        "variant_count": 9,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": "default",
                "title": "Print file",
                "additional_price": null
            },
            {
                "id": "preview",
                "title": "Mockup",
                "additional_price": null
            }
        ],
        "options": []
    },
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": 4464,
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Poster 12×12",
            "size": "12×12",
            "color": null,
            "color_code": null,
            "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/1/4464.jpg",
            "price": "9.00"
        },
```

Notice how `color` is returned as `null`. `size` can be that way to. So basically I am wanting a quicker and better way to search the returned array for the specified product_id, size, and color. So I need *returned and matching* the corresponding variants block that matches the variables submitted.

I hope I've made sense of what I'm trying to accomplish.

**UPDATE**

This is what I am needing.

So on my site the customers chooses a product, in this case a poster. Before adding it to the cart they are prompted to select a size. Let's say a 12x12. The way the API works is that it has a "top" item and then has smaller items "variants" that include the size and color. Each variant is a poster with a different size. The only way to obtain the poster product, is by receiving every variant for the poster. But each "variant" has a different "id" to send to the api to order the correct product.

So, I receive the product and it's variants in bulk or every color and size as it's own variant.

```
"variants": [
        {
            "id": 4464,
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Poster 12×12",
            "size": "12×12",
            "color": null,
            "color_code": null,
            "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/1/4464.jpg",
            "price": "9.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 1349,
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Poster 12×16",
            "size": "12×16",
            "color": null,
            "color_code": null,
            "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/1/1349.jpg",
            "price": "11.00"
        },
```

But remember the customer wanted a poster that was 12x12? We only need to send the demand to print a 12x12 poster. So we need to send to the api the ID for the variant that matches the 12x12 size.

I need a way to search through each variant for a product and find the correct variant that matches the product_id of the poster, and the size requirements of 12x12.

```
        {
            "id": 4464,
            "product_id": 1,
            "name": "Poster 12×12",
            "size": "12×12",
            "color": null,
            "color_code": null,
            "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/1/4464.jpg",
            "price": "9.00"
        },
```

Once I find that correct variant, I need to collect all that information into a new array and return it.

```
//Get the product based on the supplied product_id. ($results)
//Break that array down into just the variants. ($vars)
//Search the $vars array for a block that matches the product_id.
//Search those $vars blocks for a single one that matches the size. 
//If color is supplied, search those $vars blocks for a single one that matches the color.

//If size and color are supplied, a single block should be returned that matches all three variables (product_id, size, and color). Sometimes size and/or color is `null`. But a product_id is always supplied.
```

I hope the clears up what I am needing a little better.

Comment: Clarify your question. Do you want to search the object and just return an array with the details you specified?

Comment: I want to search the `"result" -> "variants"` (from the example shown in question. third code block) for the `product_id, size, and color` and return specific information (second code block in question) from that "block".

Comment: So you want to retrieve the product_id, size and color from the object. One thing is that the function is created wrong. I ll make one that works. Also you need json decode PHP method

Comment: I figured the function was wrong, because it wasn't working :). And the code block shown is an example from the api's website. The library I am using does the decoding for me. What is returned is actually a PHP array.

Comment: The goal would be to shorten the Code. It's always the rule to make the code smaller. You can use built in PHP functions to do that. As it looks like you have php multi-dimentional array. In order to debug I would test the code piece by piece to build it out without errors. Can you paste the code that tries to access the array.

Comment: No solution as of now.

Comment: I was at work. Just got off thats why I delayed answering your question. Message me directly and I think I can help you

Comment: Ok. I get what you want. You are passing on a product_id color size. Sometimes the color and size are null. The way you have set up the function will generate errors. What you need is to have defaults for color and probably the product should come in a certain size depending on the id. Fix that and the returned result won't be empty. Use print_r or var_dump to check if the function passes each if statement as a way of debugging your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Am also ssuming you are using php. If you have a question, asking me directly. I think I can help you but I don't know exactly what you want.

```
<?php
function get_product($object){
    $result = json_decode($object);

    $product_id = $result->result->product->id;
    $variants = $result->result->variants;

    $details = array();

    foreach($variants as $variant):
        $details[] = $variant;
    endforeach;// foreach

    return $details;
}

$json_obj = '{
    "code": 200,
    "result": {
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "POSTER",
            "brand": null,
            "model": "Poster",
            "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/poster_18x24.jpg",
            "variant_count": 9,
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": "default",
                    "title": "Print file",
                    "additional_price": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "preview",
                    "title": "Mockup",
                    "additional_price": null
                }
            ],
            "options": []
        },
        "variants": [
            {
                "id": 4464,
                "product_id": 1,
                "name": "Poster 12×12",
                "size": "12×12",
                "color": null,
                "color_code": null,
                "image": "https://d1yg28hrivmbqm.cloudfront.net/products/1/4464.jpg",
                "price": "9.00"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$array = json_decode($json_obj);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_product($json_obj));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I don't feel like this is doing quite what I am after. Check my updated question.